# Music player in c# unity doesn't work with other scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I have a toggle button, which controlls the music volume. And it works fine, but when i go to an other scene, and go back - the toggle doesn't work(doesn't change music volume). Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;
    private float volume = 1f;
    Toggle toggle;
    private void Awake()
    {
        SetMusicSingletone();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        toggle = FindObjectOfType<Toggle>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        audioSource.volume = this.volume;
    }
    public void ToggleMusic()
    {
        if (!toggle.isOn)
        {
            this.volume = 0f;
        }
        else if (toggle.isOn)
        {
            this.volume = 1f;
        }
    }
    private void SetMusicSingletone()
    {
        var music = FindObjectsOfType<Music>();
        if (music.Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The toggle uses method ToggleMusic()

Comment: Is the according AudioSource destroyed? Do you get errors in the console? If so add them to the question .. also how exactly is the `ToggleMusic` called? And why is this a Singleton?

Comment: So, the purpose for using a singleton is that I want my music to play when moving between scenes. `ToggleMusic` is called by a Toggle Button in the scene. I don't get any errors in my console. And AudioSource is not destroyed.

Comment: Just as I said the toggle doesn't work anymore when I move to the different scene and get back to this scene again.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the problem is: You have referenced the ToggleMusic method from this instance of Music in your toggle .. then you change scenes and come back .. but due to the singleton thing you destroy the Music instance linked to this new Toggle -> Toggle does nothing now.

You already have a singleton pattern so why not directly make use of it:

```c#
public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Music _singleton;
    public static Music Singleton => _singleton;

    [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

    private bool volumeOn;
    public bool MusicIsOn => volumeOn;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_singleton)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        _singleton = this;

        if(!audioSource) audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        ToggleMusic(true);
    }

    public void ToggleMusic(bool on)
    {
        audioSource.volume = on ? 1f : 0f;
        volumeOn = on;
    }

    public void ToggleMusic()
    {
        ToggleMusic(!volumeOn);        
    }
}
```

And then on your toggle instead of assigning a callback via the Inspector rather do

```c#
public class MusicToggle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Toggle toggle;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!toggle) toggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();

        toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnValueChanged);

        toggle.isOn = Music.Singleton.MusicIsOn;
    }

    private void OnValueChanged (bool on)
    {
        Music.Singleton.ToggleMusic(on);
    }
}
```